# How can I access other files in the same Docker container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-machine, pose-estimation

I'm new to Docker. When I am running my docker container, the last line in the *Dockerfile* is the following:

```
CMD ["python3", "./poses/server/server_multithreaded.py"]
```

In the *server_multithreaded.py* file described above, I am importing another file, as seen below:

```
from poses.poseapp.poseapp_sockets import PoseAppWSockets
```

When I run container using the command `docker run -p 8089:8089 zoheezus/capstone` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./poses/server/server_multithreaded.py", line 18, in <module>
      from poses.poseapp.poseapp_sockets import PoseAppWSockets
ImportError: No module named 'poses'
```

From what I understand, the 'poses' directory is not accessible or I am not accessing it the right way. **What do I need to do for server_multithreaded.py to be able to access the other files when I run it?**

The file structure of the project is the following:

[image]

Comment: Does it work outside of docker? Do those directories contain `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Assuming it works outside of docker, what is the full path to the script above in the container, and what is the value of WORKDIR in the Dockerfile

Comment: @Moylin Here is a [link] (https://github.com/zoheezus/capstone-pose-estimation/blob/master/Dockerfile) to the Dockerfile and WORKDIR is specified in there.

Comment: Checkout out atline's answer below, I find option 3 is my personal preference. WORKDIR usually solves this for me because of the framework I use adds working directory to syspath. In your dockerfile try
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/pose_recognizer

Answer (score 0):

Python won't add current working path into module search path, it will just add top level script's path into search path, of course `PYTHONPATH`, `sys path` etc. also be searched.

For your case, the current working path `/usr/pose_recognizer` won't be searched, only `/usr/pose_recognizer/poses/server` will be searched. So, definitely, it won't find module named 'poses'.

To make it work for you, give you some options:

**Option 1: Execute the `server_multithreaded.py` as module:**

```
python -m poses.server.server_multithreaded
```

**Option 2: Change `sys.path` in `server_multithreaded.py` as next before `from poses.poseapp.poseapp_sockets import PoseAppWSockets`:**

```
import sys
import os
file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)).replace('\\', '/')
lib_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(file_path, '../..')).replace('\\', '/')
sys.path.append(lib_path)
```

**Option 3: Change `PYTHONPATH` in dockerfile:**

```
WORKDIR /usr/pose_recognizer
ENV PYTHONPATH=.
CMD ["python3", "./poses/server/server_multithreaded.py"]
```

Comment: For the 3rd option, would you recommend something like:
`COPY requirements.txt /usr/pose_recognizer/requirements.txt`
`WORKDIR /usr/pose_recognizer`
`RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt`
`COPY tf_pose_estimation ./tf_pose_estimation`
`COPY . /usr/pose_recognizer`
`RUN cd tf_pose_estimation && python3 setup.py install && cd ..`
`ENV PYTHONPATH=.`
`CMD ["python3", "./poses/server/server_multithreaded.py"]`

Or do I have this formatted wrong?

Comment: Yes, any error for this? In fact you could also define `ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/pose_recognizer`, same as `.` in your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

this problem is most likely not related to docker but to your PYTHONPATH environment variable (inside the docker container). You must make sure that `capstone-pose-estimation` is in it. Furthermore, you should make `poses` and `poseapp` a package (containing `__init___.py`) in order to import from it